# Why aren't qtrees aligned horizontally if they are at the end of a theorem with qed symbol enabled?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, theorems, qtree

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{qtree}

\declaretheorem[name=Example,qed=\ensuremath{\triangleleft}]{example}
\declaretheorem[name=Example2]{example2}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
    Bla:

    \Tree [.cons [.s [.s [.s 0 ] ] ] [.cons [.s 0 ] nil ] ]
\end{example}

\begin{example2}
    Bla:

    \Tree [.cons [.s [.s [.s 0 ] ] ] [.cons [.s 0 ] nil ] ]
\end{example2}

\end{document}
```

The second one is centered, the first isn't. Why and what to do?

In the end I'd like to align several trees horizontally like that:

```
\begin{example2}
    Bla:

    \Tree [.nil ]
    \Tree [.cons 0 nil ]
    \Tree [.cons [.s [.s [.s 0 ] ] ] [.cons [.s 0 ] nil ] ]
\end{example2}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `qtree`:

> *`Qtree`* attempts to align the topmost label of the tree with the baseline of  the text, similarly to the eﬀect of the `[t]` option for `\parbox` alignment. To center trees vertically on the baseline, enclose the entire tree in a tabular environment.

You have two strategies:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{qtree}

\declaretheorem[name=Example,qed=\ensuremath{\triangleleft}]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Bla:

\raisebox{\depth}{%
  \Tree [.cons [.s [.s [.s 0 ] ] ] [.cons [.s 0 ] nil ] ]%
}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

The second strategy consists in using `tikz-qtree` that shares the same syntax with `qtree`, but is much more powerful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\declaretheorem[name=Example,qed=\ensuremath{\triangleleft}]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Bla:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tree [.cons [.s [.s [.s 0 ] ] ] [.cons [.s 0 ] nil ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

The placement is not really perfect in both cases, so some small adjustment may be necessary.

For centering, use an `equation*` environment and the `\qedhere` feature:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\declaretheorem[name=Example,qed=\ensuremath{\triangleleft}]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Bla:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tree [.cons [.s [.s [.s 0 ] ] ] [.cons [.s 0 ] nil ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}}\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see no difference for both strategies. The tree is still aligned at the left and not centered like when not using a qed symbol.

Comment: @neo I've added how to center the tree

Comment: Do you also know why the tree isn't centered?

Comment: Regarding the centering, unfortunately using an equation breaks when there are many trees which would otherwise just break to a new line. For the moment, I just work around it by using my original code and adding a white line at the end. The qed symbol then is a bit below the lowest tree leaf...

Comment: @neo I wouldn't rely on automatic line breaking in this case.

Comment: Why not? Suppose you have like 10 trees that you want to fit on one page. Then you fiddle around with settings like font size or other style related things until all trees fit on the page. Having to manually place the trees on each line for each test is quite cumbersome in this case.